# wpf ListBox Binding ObservableCollection show datas all messed up

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, observablecollection

I'm working on a windows gadget which will show a list from sharepoint
my code behind workd fine and collect the datas from sharepoint. 
and my xaml code should show the list in a listbox but the way that I've binded it show the data with one letter by line and just the first item. don't know why.

This is my xml code

```
<Page x:Class="TipsList.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Page1" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Name="ListboxTips" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding StateTitle}" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Click="OnLoad">_Load</Button>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

and this is my code behind:

```
        //The  Url
        siteUrl = "http://site/SandBox";
        //The Site Context using ClientContext class
        //This will create a Client connection to Web Application
        clientContext = new SPSClient.ClientContext(siteUrl);

        //The Web Site to Open

        clientWeb = clientContext.Web;

        var salesInfoList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tips");

        //Define the CAMLQuery this will be used to Query to the List

        SPSClient.CamlQuery Query = new SPSClient.CamlQuery();

        SPSClient.ListItemCollection listData = salesInfoList.GetItems(Query);

        //Now Execute the Query

        var queryResultSaleListItems = clientContext.LoadQuery(listData);

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        //Read the Data into the Object

        var TipsList = from Sales in queryResultSaleListItems
                        select Sales;
        ObservableCollection<Tips> colTips = new ObservableCollection<Tips>();
        //Read Every List Item and Display Data into the DataGrid
        foreach (SPSClient.ListItem item in TipsList)
        {

            var tips = new Tips();
            tips.StateTitle = item.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(2).ToString();
            tips.ProductName = item.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(4).ToString();
            tips.Quantity = item.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(5).ToString();

            colTips.Add(tips);
        }
        ListboxTips.DataContext = colTips;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log error (including InnerExceptions!)
        // Handle exception
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml code, change

```
<ListBox Name="ListboxTips" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding StateTitle}" />
```

to

```
<ListBox Name="ListboxTips" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StateTitle}"/>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Little shorter

```
   <ListBox Name="ListboxTips" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding ColTips}" DisplayMemeberPath=StateTitle />
```

If you had already set the context to ColTips then you don't need and ItemsSource